# Twitter API returns error: SSL is required(92)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, twitter

I'd like to acquire user's tweets.
Following code is using twitter API and acquiring user's tweets.
But log outputs `data:{"errors":[{"message":"SSL is required","code":92}]}`

```
- (void)getJSON
{
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json"];
    OAConsumer* consumer = [[OAConsumer alloc]initWithKey:kTwitterAPIKey secret:kTwitterAPISecret];
    OAMutableURLRequest* request = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url consumer:consumer token:_responseToken realm:nil signatureProvider:nil];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    OADataFetcher* fetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc]init];
    [fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request delegate:self didFinishSelector:@selector(getData:didFinishWithData:) didFailSelector:@selector(failedToGet:didFailWithError:)];
}

- (void)getData:(OAServiceTicket *)ticket didFinishWithData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSString* responseBody = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"data:%@", responseBody);
}
```

I need to use SSL? How do I use SSL?
Do you have any idea?

Comment: try change http:// to https://

Comment: Thank you.It run correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Use "https" in your URL:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json
```

That must be enough to solve the problem.

Comment: Eduardo, that did in fact solve the problem the original poster had put up one year ago, but it would probably be polite to give credit to the person who posted it first in the comments.

Comment: @AHiggins Oh! I am so sorry. I didn't notice the response from Bimawa. I saw no answers so I thought it was not solved yet.

Comment: No problem!  That's why I mentioned it - I wasn't sure if you had noticed or not.